# Failed to start websocket connection: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred

Tags: java, kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-eks

General information:
Jenking is running on EKS version 1.27
Jenkins version 2.401.1

Installed plugins:

- Kubernetes Client API Plugin Version6.4.1-215.v2ed17097a_8e9
- Kubernetes Credentials Plugin Version0.10.0
- Kubernetes Credentials Provider Version1.225.v14f9e6b_28f53
- Kubernetes plugin Version3985.vd26d77b_2a_48a_

**The pod starts to boot, and once the container is built it throws an error as follows:**

```
Failed to start websocket connection: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
Failed to start websocket connection: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:129)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:122)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReady(Utils.java:174)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReadyOrFail(Utils.java:184)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.setupConnectionToPod(PodOperationsImpl.java:365)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.exec(PodOperationsImpl.java:286)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.doLaunch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:448)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.launch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:335)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:509)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:134)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:322)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor612.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:110)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor612.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CastBlock$ContinuationImpl.cast(CastBlock.java:47)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor730.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor596.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:422)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.http.WebSocketHandshakeException
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpWebSocketImpl$1.onFailure(OkHttpWebSocketImpl.java:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.kt:592)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$connect$1.onResponse(RealWebSocket.kt:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    ... 3 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: waiting here
```

We tried to downgrade the image to an earlier image. (It didn't help.)
Also tried to modify the plugin versions – same result.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem

This is my version information

Jenkins version: 2.375.1
Kubernetes version: 3923.v294a_d4250b_91
kubernetes-cli：1.12.0
kubernetes-client-api version： 6.4.1-215.v2ed17097a_8e9
kubernetes-credentials version： 0.10.0
kubernetes-pipeline-devops-steps version： 1.6

Comment: Pardon me but I don't understand. Are you saying that the OP needs to use these versions of Jenkins and Kubernetes?

Comment: You need to add answers here sir, not report issues.